# array of all languages in English - iOS

Tags: ios, localization, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to look for an array of all languages written specifically in English.
I've read several questions about this subject, and I noticed this line of code:

```
NSArray *languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

"languages" array-object holds all langauges string, but the problem is that it's written in the language that's defined in my iPhone. I want it to be in English for all devices.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the default language to be "en" then query the languages list and set it back to the previous one. Something like this (not tested thought)

```
    NSArray *languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //your query here

    //restore the previous
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but after I'm using : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];NSArray *englishArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; "englishArray" has just one object and not even in English.. do you have any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *localIdentifiers = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
    NSMutableArray *lanuages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [localIdentifiers count]; i++) {

        [lanuages addObject:[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[localIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
     NSLog(@"%@", lanuages);
```

Try this or You can use another method

```
NSArray* languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [languages count]; i++) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[languages objectAtIndex:i]]);

    }
```

Comment: The first method prints butch of data (I think), not strings. The second method doesnt do anything, still prints the languages in the default language of the device.